# Unable to connect to wifi after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless

After updating to 22.04 LTS, everything is perfectly fine but I am unable to connect to wifi because there is no wifi option in settings, but in previous version 21.10 it was working fine.

Output of

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2114]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Not working in my case

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 question  edited

Comment: You probably manually installed some driver for your wireless device, that is incompatible with the new kernel.

Comment: where can I found drivers?

Comment: I have no idea what you installed and if the device is supported by the new kernel without any driver. Some research is needed. Try to boot with a Live USB and check if Wi-Fi works there.

Comment: Working on Live USB, how can I install driver using Live USB?

Answer (score -1):

You need to see your wlan0 interface after typing this command:

```
ls /sys/class/net
```

or

```
ip link show
```

If there is a device, you may want to try this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Of course we don't know your wifi interface code. You need to learn it from sys/class/net folder.

This also might help:

```
systemctl restart networkmanager
```

Comment: This won't work because a kernel module is not loaded.